# Can I specify column types when creating an SQL Server view?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Seeking to enforce more strict type safety and make it easier to detect mistakes, I would like to specify column types of my view explicitly.

But while this works:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myview] (
    [a],
    [b],
    [c]
)
AS
SELECT 'a1', 'b1', 'c1';
```

this fails:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myview] (
    [a] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
    [b] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
    [c] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL
)
AS
SELECT 'a1', 'b1', 'c1';
```

Is there a correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

SQL Server has to deduce the types - but you can force its hand if you need to:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myview] (
    [a],
    [b],
    [c]
)
AS
SELECT
   CONVERT(nvarchar(32),'a1'),
   CONVERT(nvarchar(32),'b1'),
   CONVERT(nvarchar(32),'c1');
```

As for the null/non-null side of things, again, SQL Server has to deduce this. If you have a column that you know will be `not null` but SQL Server is getting it incorrect, you can wrap it in an `ISNULL` statement with a non-null second argument:

```
SELECT ISNULL(ColumnSQLServerThinksCanBeNull,'abc')
```

And it will then describe the column as `not null`. The second value doesn't matter (after all, this is about my own assertion that the column will never be null), so long as it's of a compatible type to the column.

Comment: I've tried this problem using CAST() instead of CONVERT() and the view still kept the original "guessed data types". CONVERT() forces it before the view "forces it". Thanks!

Comment: Not your fault, but SQL views are meant to simplfy queries, not that you have intimate knowledge of each column datatype in order to ease the DBs life.

Comment: @alejandrob - SQL views can fulfil many different purposes. If you only use them to simplify queries, so be it, but don't dismiss that others may use them differently.

Comment: Indeed, last week I found a use for this, and works beautifully. Thanks.